# How to download & store files in android in internal storage and access it?

Tags: android, file, storage

I would like to download files from the web to the internal storage of the android device so that it will not be available for the user manipulation and how to access the stored file.For instance a csv file,any example or snippets on this will be helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

For Accessing the stored file, this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidFileSystem/article.html) might help.

If you want to know about downloading files, then check [this](http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2011/04/android-development-downloading-a-file-from-the-web/)

Comment: simply pointing to an external link is not a good answer. Also one of the link is broken.